# Get запрос в модальное окно bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, html, php

Ситуация такая - модальное окно вызывается с наличием параметра href

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
```

в моем случае у меня на странице 2 таких ссылки, у которых href имеют вид

```
 href="change.php?s=1"
 href="change.php?s=2"
```

В самом change.php стоит var_dump GET массива (собсна его я вижу в модальном окне).
Так вот проблема: при клике на ссылку 1 - он показывает 1. Если окно закрыть и нажать на ссылку 2 - все равно показывает 1. Правильно отрабатывает только первый клик после обновления страницы. Это можно как-то вылечить?

Answer (score 2):

Можно добавить вот такой javascript на страницу

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Comment: Дико извиняюсь: что это должно в теории дать ? ПОсле закрытия окна что происходит ?
Где про это можно почитать ? Нужна дока jquery или в bootstrap рыться ?
Спасибо

Comment: Это не работает. Уничтожается только содержимое модального окна, а параметры GET запроса к этому окну не меняются.